# systemctl-service имеет статус active для python скрипта, но выполнения не происходит

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, systemd, lubuntu

Все очень просто. Есть Python-скрипт /home/user/test/test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from time import sleep

while True:
    with open('log.txt','a') as f:
        f.write('one'+'\n')
    sleep(5)
```

Создадим service:
    sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/test.service

```
[Unit]
Description=test
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/user/test/test.py
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Я хочу его корректной работы в планировщике:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable test.service
sudo systemctl start test.service
sudo systemctl status test.service
```

Получаю ответ

```
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/test.service; enabled; vendor preset:
Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-12-19 19:37:01 GMT; 14min ago
Main PID: 965 (python3)
Tasks: 4 (limit: 2337)
CGroup: /system.slice/test.service
       └─965 /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/test/test.py
```

НО ПОЧЕМУ ТОГДА НИЧЕГО НЕ ПИШЕТСЯ В log.txt
Он создается если я просто запускаю ./test.py.
Все права выставлены на максимум. Reboot на Ubuntu18 делал. Пробовал Type=simple. Дублирование файла в /lib/systemd/system/test.service тоже не помогло. Помогите.
Пожалуйста, повторите создание сервиса таким образом, что не так тут?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена добавлением строки рабочей директории

```
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/test
```